problem with k nearest neighbour when there are multiple equal distance points
Here is the problem I'm trying to solve.
In a two-class problem, the two-dimensional training samples of each class are given. Estimate p(x|$\omega_i$), i = 1,2 at x = (0,0) using the k-nearest-neighbor method with $k_n$= 3. Use the unbiased estimate and city block distance.
class 1 points are (-3,0)(-3,0.5)(-3,1)(-2.5,0)(-2.5,0.5)(-2.5,1)(-2,0)(-1,0)(-1,1)
class 2 points are (1,0)(1,1)(1,-1)(1.5,0.5)(2,0)(2,0.5)
My problem is that the distances of points (-1,0) and (1,0) to (0,0) are 1. Multiple points with a distance of 2 exist. So, which one should be taken as the nearest neighbour?
